# How do I determine the active wireless SSID?

Tags: mono, wireless, ifconfig, iwconfig

I'm trying to find the name of my active wireless network, out of a list of all available networks.

In order to list all available wireless networks, I call

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

which gives me a very long output. I can pipe that through a python script found on [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88967) called `iwlistparse.py` which gives me the pertinent information in a concise format:

```
Name                                               Address             Quality   Channel   Encryption
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    59 %     6         WEP
MonkeyIsland                                       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    53 %     2         WPA v.1
JustChillaxing                                     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    50 %     6         WPA v.1
RubberDucky                                        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    44 %     11        WPA v.1
GrapeVine                                          XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    41 %     11        WEP
CompanyPrinter_HP_Officejet_6700                   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    41 %     6         Open
WhyYouSniffinMySSID                                XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    41 %     11        WEP
IAintSniffingYoSSID                                XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    39 %     11        Open
ShaddupYouTwo_FreeWifiForAll                       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    39 %     6         Open
```

This does not tell me the name of my active wifi, though. For that, I use `iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MonkeyIsland"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-75 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:40  Invalid misc:138   Missed beacon:0
```

From that, I can grep for `ESSID` and extract the name, and try to match that against the names returned from `iwlist`.

But is there an easier way to do this?

I'm *not* using [Network Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) or [wicd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd) (BeagleBone Black + Debian w/ hard floats enabled + mono + various USB wifi dongles == hardware/driver compatibility issues)

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking try

```
iwgetid -r
```

which will return the ssid